# How to use filter in map

Tags: filter, dataweave

I have following code:

```
%dw 2.0 output application/json var attributeIdMapping =
 ${vault::attributeIdMapping}
--- {
     "objectTypeId": 3,
     "attributes": vars.requestBody mapObject (value, key) ->
        {
            "objectTypeAttributeId": (attributeIdMapping.attributes filter ($.name == key))[0].id,
            "objectAttributeValues": [{
             "value": value,
             "key": key
         }] 
        } }
```

attributeIdMapping:

```
{
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "accountType",
            "id": "87"
        },
        {
            "name": "accountClass",
            "id": "89"
        },
        {
            "name": "accountName",
            "id": "85"
        },
        {
            "name": "displayName",
            "id": "18"
        },
        {
            "name": "accountCategory",
            "id": "88"
        },
        {
            "name": "accountNumber",
            "id": "84"
        },
        {
            "name": "description",
            "id": "86"
        },
        {
            "name": "accountGroup",
            "id": "90"
        }
    ]
}
```

vars.requestBody:

```
{
    "displayName": "TestMulesoft2",
    "description": "Test"
}
```

But my filter shows null in the end. As I understand key is not passed to level below map itself. How can I get this working?

Comment: You need to be clear with your inputs and usage. What does vars.requestBody holds ? what attributeIdMapping.attributes holds ? Why are you filtering $.name with key aka index IDs ?

Comment: Hello. Updated original post with variables values.
Just as additional comment, code is working as it should if I change key is filter to "description", for example.

Comment: What is the expected output if it worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put all the input data inside the script to simplify reproduction. The problem seems to be using the operator `==` to compare a string and a key types returns empty. Using the operator `~=` which [attempts to coerce](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-operators#equality-and-relational-operators) appears to return the expected result:

```
%dw 2.0 
output application/json 
var attributeIdMapping =
{
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "accountType",
            "id": "87"
        },
        {
            "name": "accountClass",
            "id": "89"
        },
        {
            "name": "accountName",
            "id": "85"
        },
        {
            "name": "displayName",
            "id": "18"
        },
        {
            "name": "accountCategory",
            "id": "88"
        },
        {
            "name": "accountNumber",
            "id": "84"
        },
        {
            "name": "description",
            "id": "86"
        },
        {
            "name": "accountGroup",
            "id": "90"
        }
    ]
}
var requestBody = {
    "displayName": "TestMulesoft2",
    "description": "Test"
}
--- {
     "objectTypeId": 3,
     "attributes": requestBody mapObject (value, key) ->
        {
            "objectTypeAttributeId": (attributeIdMapping.attributes filter ($.name ~= key))[0].id,
            "objectAttributeValues": [{
             "value": value,
             "key": key
         }] 
        } }
```

Output:

```
{
  "objectTypeId": 3,
  "attributes": {
    "objectTypeAttributeId": "18",
    "objectAttributeValues": [
      {
        "value": "TestMulesoft2",
        "key": "displayName"
      }
    ],
    "objectTypeAttributeId": "86",
    "objectAttributeValues": [
      {
        "value": "Test",
        "key": "description"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Another question though.
Is there easy way to get every mapped values to object?
So it would be like:
`{
    "objectTypeId": 3,
    "attributes": [{
        "objectTypeAttributeId": 18,
        "objectAttributeValues": [{
            "value": "TestMulesoft"
        }]
    },
    {
        "objectTypeAttributeId": 86,
        "objectAttributeValues": [{
            "value": "TestMulesoft"
        }]
    }]
}`

Comment: Solved it by using pluck instead of mapObject.